# Upgradable & Plugin Based Application Development

Tags: c#, c++, plugins

i have been writing applications in VC++ & VC#.

I know how to provide user with customization for the whole application & its functionality and all.

But what i have been impressed with is Mozilla Firefox & its plugin. I can find plugin for almost any customization i want:

Multi-row bookmarks, Automatic Save Folder, Block Site, User Profiles, Flash Video Saver, Page Rank Tool, Facebook Updates and every other stupid\ingenious thing you want in your browser.

That got me thinking how far did Mozilla think before developing the base program, i.e "Firefox" with its custom settings. I mean they put in flexibility so that there could be multiple lines of bookmarks & user can select to show how many and rest will be in scroll-down. And this and all the other stuff.

All this functionality that comes from plugins, how.

If i want to make a software\application that can have upgrades\plugins\patches. How to di it.

- **Where & What do i need to start learning?**

*My idea of doing this is to write separate DLLs for a lot of things of the application\software and everything of software is defined in DLL and no matter an update\patch\plugin, just modify\upgrade\replace the DLL and you can do this.*

Answer (score 1):

It's a complex subject, but you might want to check out MEF at http://mef.codeplex.com/ which is a framework that guides you down creating pluggable managed applications.  I remember the hands on labs being a good starter, although it was a few versions ago I last looked at it.